# Oracle spool file to a .txt file. Options for headings

Tags: oracle

I'm trying to spool an Oracle file to a .txt file.  I want to display the headings but I am doing a TRIM to eliminate extra spaces and the 'TRIM' is showing up in the header, when I have more fields, some of the headings do not show up because it is too long.  How can I either eliminate spaces in between the fields or get my headings to show up with just the field name?

```
set newpage none;
set space 0;
set feedback off; 
set linesize 5000;
set pagesize 50000; 
set echo off;
set termout off;
set trimspool on;
set colsep '|';
set heading on;
set headsep on;
set underline off;
set trim on;

spool /dch/sap_load/ZPONE_MCC/QE1/mock3/test_export.txt


SELECT
TRIM(    MATNR                  )|| '|' || 
TRIM(    WERKS                  )|| '|' || 
TRIM(    STLAN                  )|| '|' || 
TRIM(    DATUV                  )|| '|' || 
TRIM(    BMEIN                  )|| '|' || 
TRIM(    BMENG                  )|| '|' ||
TRIM(    STLAL                  )|| '|' ||
TRIM(    STLST                  )|| '|' ||
TRIM(    ZTEXT                  )|| '|' ||
TRIM(    AENNR                  )|| '|' ||
TRIM(    REVLV                  )|| '|' ||
TRIM(    LABOR                  )
FROM CLS_MCC1XX_BOM_HEADER;
```

This is how my output looks: 
[image]

Thanks,
Marcie

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a column alias as Matthew Strawbridge suggests, but you'd have to enclose it in double-quotes not single quotes:

```
SELECT ...
AS "MATNR|WERKS|STLAN|DATUV|BMEIN|BMENG|STLAL|STLST|ZTEXT|AENNR|REVLV|LABOR"
FROM CLS_MCC1XX_BOM_HEADER;
```

and more importantly you're restricted by the maximum length of an identifier, 30 characters, so this won't work here.

Another option is to make your fake header instead:

```
set heading off
prompt MATNR|WERKS|STLAN|DATUV|BMEIN|BMENG|STLAL|STLST|ZTEXT|AENNR|REVLV|LABOR
SELECT ...
FROM CLS_MCC1XX_BOM_HEADER;
```

You suppress the real, unhelpful header, with `set heading off` (or `set pagesize 0`) and instead use the `prompt` SQL*Plus command to write the text you want.

You could also `select '<your header>' from dual` rather then using `prompt`, but I find it a bit cleaner.

Answer (score 0):

By concatenating the trimmed strings you end up outputting a single field.

One option is just to rename that field:

```
SELECT
TRIM(    MATNR                  )|| '|' ||
TRIM(    WERKS                  )|| '|' ||
TRIM(    STLAN                  )|| '|' ||
TRIM(    DATUV                  )|| '|' ||
TRIM(    BMEIN                  )|| '|' ||
TRIM(    BMENG                  )|| '|' ||
TRIM(    STLAL                  )|| '|' ||
TRIM(    STLST                  )|| '|' ||
TRIM(    ZTEXT                  )|| '|' ||
TRIM(    AENNR                  )|| '|' ||
TRIM(    REVLV                  )|| '|' ||
TRIM(    LABOR                  )
AS 'whatever heading you want'
FROM CLS_MCC1XX_BOM_HEADER;
```